# Unable to Map Data Type in Spring JPA using Projections

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to Fetch Data from Posgresql DB using Projection Interface but Unable to Map UUID to the Projection correctly. I can always cast it as text or byte and then convert back to UUID but that isn't the most efficient approach for the whole project with multiple queries.

UserProjection.class

```
import java.util.UUID;
public interface UserProjection {
UUID getUserId();
}
```

UserTestRepo.class

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public interface UserTestRepo extends JpaRepository<UserTest, UUID> {   
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select user_id as userId from user_test")
    public List<UserProjection> getProjectionData();
}
```

UserTest.class

```
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
@Table(name = "user_test")
@Entity
public class UserTest {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    public UUID userId;
}
```

Execution Statements :

```
List<UserProjection> list = userRepo.getProjectionData();
        System.out.println(list.get(0).getUserId());
```

PosgresSQL Structures is a simple UUID entry.
I am getting No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query: `@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select user_id as userId from user_test")` ***is returning a list of userId from user_test table, not a list of  UserProjection***. So, you can either declare a constructor and project your values there or just take return a list of userId in your query method.
Simply try this:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select user_id as userId from user_test")
public List<UUID> getProjectionData();
```

Or

```
@Query(nativeQuery = false, value = "select new full_dto_path.UserProjection(user_id) from UserTest")
 public List<UserProjection> getProjectionData();
```

Before applying second approach, make sure you have defined your constructor for that single field.

Note: full_dto_path means the fully qualified path of your UserProjection dto.

Hope this will work.

Comment: The second approach worked with a minor correction of removing "nativeQuery = true" and using UserTest instead of user_test .Used the second approach as I have to build multiple data fields upon that query.

Comment: @Harshil, yes, my mistake, cause second approach is not a native query, but the first one is. Will correct the ans